# PHP form works in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: php, forms, google-chrome, email, firefox

Okay so fairly straight forward php contact form. It submits and sends the data in ie and takes the user to a thank you page. However in both google chrome and firefox, my users are taken to the thank you page but their form data is not sent to the email.
This is the code I am using:
**Form Data on one page**

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="send_wl.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="16%">First Name</td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="82%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td width="16%">Last Name</td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="82%"><input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="address" cols="50" rows="4" id="address"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date of Birth</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="dob" type="date" id="dob" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Health Care Number</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="phn" type="text" id="phn" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="ac" type="text" id="ac" size="3"><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="7"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comments</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="4" id="comment"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**php script on another pages "send_wl.php"**

```
<?php 
    $to = "ouremail@gmail.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'] ; 
    $name = $_POST['name'] ; 
    $headers = "From: $from"; 
    $subject = "New Patient Data"; 

    $fields = array(); 
    $fields["name"] = "name";
    $fields["lastname"} = "lastname"; 
    $fields["address"] = "address"; 
    $fields["email"] = "email";
    $fields["ac"] = "ac"; 
    $fields["phone"] = "phone"; 
    $fields["dob"] = "dob";
    $fields["phn"] = "phn";
    $fields["comment"] = "comment"; 

    $body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){    $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

    $headers2 = "From: noreply@ourwebsite.com"; 
    $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
    $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, please consult our website at www.ourwebsite.com";


    if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";
    } else { 
        if($name == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";
        } else { 
            $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
            }
            if($send) 
                {header( "Location: http://www.thewebsite.com/thankyou.html" );} 
            else 
                {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify mailreciepient@gmail.com"; } 
        }
    }
?>
```

I have made all the suggested changes to the web site as well and this form is still not working.

Should I also be removing the   = "lastname" from the  $fields["lastname"] = "lastname" I know it seems like a stupid question but I am honestly pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: Add session_start(); as first line on both pages then try in Chrome/Firefox

Comment: Vineet1982 what would that solve?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "their form data is not sent to the email"?  Does the email get sent but it's missing data?

Comment: sorry no.  no email is sent

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not browser dependant, it is the server, so as long as the same server is running, that the output would be the same.

Your issue is in fact, your code.

All of your  references to $fields, needs to be:  $fields["dob"] because it is a hash map.  That way when fetching data, it will do it correctly... as your keys were wrong when it was searching about.

```
if($from == '') {
  print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";
} elseif ($name == ''){
  print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";
} else { 
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
    $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
    if($send && $send2){  //<--   check both flags?
        header( "Location: http://www.thewebsite.com/thankyou.html" );
    }else{
        print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify mailreciepient@gmail.com";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this and repost if there are further issues.... AGAIN many thanks

Comment: this did not fix the issue

Comment: which of your error codes did you receive?  "We Encounted an error sending your mail..."  ?

Comment: what if $send it set to true, but $send2 is not, so it would still fire the success despite the error.

Comment: there is no error it also is no longer working in ie with the changes.  now the form when submitted takes the viewer to the thank you page and no email is sent.  and the user has no idea that it didn't work.

Comment: I hope this isnt too late, but i will post a solution later today when i get off of work, if it is not too late, that you can more or less just copy+paste as a working system.  Ill edit my post about 7pm EST.

Comment: i will start with your solution and debug it to make one which works. and then after that i will write a detailed report for you to understand what was going on

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST? Also any $fields{"fieldname"} should be $fields["comment"]

Comment: Thank you I will try the latter and then the former if the latter doesn't work... many thanks

Comment: ADd these error_reporing(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); to display any errors.. Also try var_dump($send); after you assign the mail function to it. It will display your errors.